# Struggling with getchar() function in C

Tags: c++, c, string, input, getchar

I am trying to replace multiple blanks with a single blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLINE 500

main() {
    char text[MAXLINE];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; (text[i] = getchar()) != EOF && text[i] != 'x'; i++) {
        if(text[i] == ' ')
            i++;

        while((text[i] = getchar()) != EOF && text[i] != 'x' && text[i] == ' ');

        if(text[i] == EOF || text[i] == 'x')
            break;
    }

    text[i] = '\0';

    printf("\n\n-- Result --\n%s", text);
}
```

I know that `getchar()` expects a character after `enter` was pressed, but I have seen many times, how people use it to get a whole string till `EOF` is found. Even in this example, it works if I comment out the `while` loop (I get a correct string if I write a single word without blanks). What I want is to put every single char that a person writes in an array. Is `getchar()` function okay to use in this case? If yes, what do I need to change in this code to make it work, because now it prints only some characters (if the `while` loop is not commented out)? As I said, it works if I write a word `apple` or similar without any blanks and without the `while` loop.

Comment: Note that `main()` should (must) return `int`. And you should test for overflow (`i < MAXLINE`).

Comment: thanks. I will fix these once I'm done with the current problem.

Comment: Also note that `getchar()`, despite it's very communicative name, [does *not* return a `char`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) (since `EOF` does not fit in a char).

Comment: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-remove-spaces-string

Comment: yes, but I am using a char array, which converts the integer that `getchar` returns to ASCII character.

Comment: @decas The problem is that it doesn't convert the result to a `char` it simply pretends it is a `char`. If `EOF` doesn't fit into a `char` then you will never reach it, or you may reach it too soon. Store the result of `getchar()` in an `int` and when it's suitable for your output store it in `text`.

Comment: @Kninnug okay, what about this code: http://pastebin.com/26gbbqa7 What's wrong here?

Comment: What is your input. What is your output. What is your expected output?

Comment: Input: applex. Output: ap. Expected: apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read all the input from user until end of input, skiping spaces which occurs several times in line, use something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLINE 500

int main() {
    char text[MAXLINE];
    int i;
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    for (i = 0; c != EOF && i < MAXLINE-1; ++i) {
        text[i] = c;

        if ( c != ' ' ) {
            c = getchar();
        } else {
            while ( c == ' ' )
                c = getchar();
        }
    }
    text[i] = '\0';

    printf("\n\n-- Result --\n%s", text);
}
```

Comment: thank you. What did I do wrong with my `getchar` implementation?

Comment: @decas You assigned the results to a `char`.  On a typical implementation with 8 bit bytes, `getchar` has 257 different possible return values, so the results don't fit in a `char` without loss.

Comment: In your code, you increment `i` only when space occurs, so I might bet, that you get an array of first char of every word. And storing result of `getchar()` in `char` is also wrong.

Comment: @JamesKanze The main trouble with `char` and `getchar()` is not number of possible return values of `getchar()` but signedness of `char`. Because standard doesn't specify whether `char` is signed or unsigned, with `EOF` equal to `-1`, it stores unsigned `255` in char. Then comparing char with EOF is comparing `unsigned char` with  negative constant, which is totally always is false.

Comment: @JamesKanze if the problem is only with `getchar` result assigned to a char, then why this code still doesn't work? http://pastebin.com/26gbbqa7

Comment: In your while loop you reassign `text[i]` even if you don't want this. You read next char on every while check. So with every for-loop iteration you read at least two chars of input.

Comment: So, you should place your while-loop inside your if.

Comment: @rasen Are you sure you read the correct code? I am not assigning `text[i]` in the new code in the `while` loop. In addition, I was reassigning `text[i]` with new input just to skip blanks. I do not need blanks, so I just reassign the first found blank and exit the `while` loop once not a blank is found.

Comment: `while((text[i] = getchar()) != EOF && text[i] != 'x' && text[i] == ' ');` this is, without doubt, your code.

Comment: In code under link, you don't assign your input in while at all, while reading minimum one extra symbol from input

Comment: @rasen I was talking about http://pastebin.com/26gbbqa7 In the new code, I skip all the blanks. I only assign a new value in the char array, if it's not `EOF`, `x` and a blank.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33359/discussion-between-rasen-and-decas)

Comment: thanks to @rasen. we solved the problem. This is the solution: http://pastebin.com/zW2uNFXD

Comment: @rasen The problem is _not_ the signedness of `char`.  Whether
plain `char` is signed or unsigned, it doesn't work, because (on
a machine with 8 bit bytes), `getchar` must be able to return
257 different values: `0xFF` is a valid `char` value (perhaps
negative, but still valid); on many of the machines I have
worked on, it corresponded to `'ÿ'`.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`, since it must be able
to return one more value than can fit in a `char`.  It is
a programming error to assign the results to a `char`, since you
loose critical information.  Depending on whether plain `char`
is signed or unsigned, checking for `EOF` after having assigned
it to a char will mean that you can never find `EOF` (plain
`char` unsigned), or that a certain character on input (`ÿ` in
Latin 1, typically) will be treated as `EOF`.

In C++, the equivalent is `std::cin.get()`, but we would more
generally write something like:

```
for ( int i = 0;
        i < sizeof( text ) && std::cin.get( text[i]) && text[i] != 'x';
        ++ i ) {
    //  ...
}
```

(Of course, in C++, we'd most likely use an std::string, with
just a single `char` or `int` for the input.)

In C (since it looks like that's what you're actually using),
you need an extra intermediate variable:

```
int ch;
for ( int i = 0;
        i < sizeof(text) && (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != 'x';
        ++ i ) {
    text[i] = ch;
    //  ...
}
```

Note too that in both languages, you need the bounds check as
the first condition.  (In C++, you don't need it if you're using
`std::string`.)

Comment: yes, I failed to remember that `EOF` is -1 and I am using a char.

Comment: @decas `EOF` is _usually_ -1.  All that is required is that it be negative (and `getchar` returns either `EOF` or a value in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]`).

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop reads without incrementing `i`. So all characters read are in fact thrown away because they are overwritten by the next loop. If it's only up to replacing multiple blank by one blank you might do something like that

```
char text[1024];
int  i;
int  c;

for(i = 0; i < sizeof(text)-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != 'x'; ) {
     if( c != ' ' || i == 0 || text[i-1] != ' ' )
           text[i++] = c;
}
```

As already statetd in comments: Don't directly assign the result of `getchar()` directly to a char, otherwise comparing a byte read to EOF might result in being true although you haven't reached end-of-file yet.

Comment: Yes, I am throwing blanks away, because I need only one.